# save hash in csv file under particular header

Tags: csv, perl, hash

I have one hash in the format of

```
$VAR1 = {
   'ALPA' => 51,
   'BETA' => 39
};
```

I want to save hash in csv with header alpha and beta in the form of

```
ALPA BETA
51   39
```

Please guide me on this as i am new to perl .

Comment: Use [`print`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html). And read a [Perl tutorial](https://www.perltutorial.org/).

Comment: In the future, please show in your question the code that you have tried. This is not relevant now, since you got a few answers anyhow. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output as csv format, I'll use

```
my $VAR1 = {
  'ALPA' => 51,
  'BETA' => 39
};

my @k = (); # remember all the keys
my @v = (); # remember all the values in corresponding order
foreach my $k (keys(%{$VAR1})) {
  push(@k, $k);
  push(@v, $VAR1->{$k});
}
print(join(",", @k) . "\n"); # concat with comma in between
print(join(",", @v) . "\n");
```

On my computer, this results

```
BETA,ALPA
39,51
```

If you want the output to be Tab-Separated Values, you can replace the `,` in `join` function with `\t`.

However, as far as I know, you can never preserve the order of key-value pairs in your hash variable declaration. If you do want to, you need another array which stores all the keys in right order.

Comment: Can't use string ("$VAR1 = {
          'alpha => 51,"...) as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use } Iam geting error in this

Comment: Could you post your entire program, or are your testing mine?

Comment: i am using ur program to run

Comment: i saved my output in one hash which shows the output when i use print function  
print Dumper(\%sGrpHash); produce the  the output like $VAR1 = {
   'ALPA' => 51,
   'BETA' => 39
};

Comment: The error message should point out on which line this error occurred. And could you paste the original error message quoted by ``.

Comment: the line at which u declare  "$VAR1 = { 'alpha => 51,"......) in this .actually i have info in hash function . so can u tell me how to save hash into csv file . secondlly  this lines "$VAR1 = { 'alpha => 51,"......)  comes when we use print with dumper . so can u tell me how can i proceed with my hash

Answer (score 0):

CSV stands for 'Comma Separated Values', in your output there are no commas

Please inspect the following sample code if it complies with your requirements

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %hash = (
   'ALPA' => 51,
   'BETA' => 39
);

say join(',',keys   %hash);
say join(',',values %hash);
```

Output

```
ALPA,BETA
51,39
```